# Can't print table with angularjs, HTML and REST

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

I am quite new to the mentioned technologies in the question. Trying to generate table by using them. Currently, I can get json format of the table from browser but can not print even in console (in `.js` file). What would be the reason here?

**HTML**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app>
<head>
<title>Book</title>
 <script src="index.js"></script>
 </head>
  <body background="/images/library-wall.jpg">

    <center>
   <div data-ng-app="bookApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="bookListCtrl">
        <table border = "1">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th color = "#0000FF">Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>ISBN</th>
                <th>Brief Description</th>
                <th>Location</th>
            </tr>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="book in books">
                <td>{{book.id}}</td>
                <td>{{book.title}}</td>
                <td>{{book.author}}</td>
                <td>{{book.isbn}}</td>
                <td>{{book.description}}</td>
                <td>{{book.location}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
var booksApp = angular.module('booksApp', []);
books.controller('bookListCtrl', function($scope, $http) {  
$http.get('books').success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.books = data;
});
});
```

**REST**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/books", method = RequestMethod.GET)
ResponseEntity<Collection<Book>> allOffices() {
    return new ResponseEntity<Collection<Book>>(bookRepository.findAll(),
            HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure REST returns any data? Have you tried to print some string instead of response value?

Comment: I printed the values in browser, and it works fine.

Comment: What about data? Can you verify service returns data?

Comment: @RaufAgayev Please write full html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML
>   document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define
>   the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple
>   applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them
>   using angular.bootstrap instead. AngularJS applications cannot be
>   nested within each other.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp

Try:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Book</title>
 <script src="index.js"></script>
 </head>
  <body background="/images/library-wall.jpg">

    <center>
   <div data-ng-app="bookApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="bookListCtrl">
        <table border = "1">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th color = "#0000FF">Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>ISBN</th>
                <th>Brief Description</th>
                <th>Location</th>
            </tr>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="book in books">
                <td>{{book.id}}</td>
                <td>{{book.title}}</td>
                <td>{{book.author}}</td>
                <td>{{book.isbn}}</td>
                <td>{{book.description}}</td>
                <td>{{book.location}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var booksApp = angular.module('booksApp', []);
books.controller('
```

Shouldn't it be **booksApp**.controller?

Comment: Ok, so, the console.log(data) works? Can you post it's output?

Comment: console.log(data) doesn't print anything. I assume that problem is related with html part :/

Comment: Ok, so it can be a problem with your webservice, does it work if you call it with something else than angular?

Comment: Ok, on Chrome dev console, in thenetwork tab, do you see the call to your webservice? If you replace $scope.books with an handwritten array in your controller, it works?

Answer (score 0):

How to check my web service and web page that they are running:

First, to use `Postman` to send web service a request with GET method. If you receive the response, it means successful.

Second, to lookup angularjs document find your error. Suppose your web service's host is `http://127.0.0.1:5000`, please set the `url` to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/books`.

Please be sure that client-side and server side are able to work.